# Two services, same domain on GCP?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, dns, reverse-proxy, devops

I'm facing a problem that I can't find ways to easily solved it on Google Cloud.

Today, I have an AWS Account with several systems running on a Kubernetes cluster, Lambda functions and Elastic Beanstalk. For accessing them, I use an API Gateway like this:

```
Domain xpto.com
   |----------------> xpto.com/login    -> Lambda Function
   |----------------> xpto.com/users    -> Kubernetes Cluster
   |----------------> xpto.com/employee -> Elastic Beanstalk
```

So, I have the same domain with different paths and each of those paths is redirected to one specific place where a service is running.

The problem is, I didn't find a way to "translate" this API Gateway rules to GCP.

Is there a native way to it? And if isn't, how do you guys recommend a way to solve this (DNS, reverse proxy, ...)?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why not works install some api gateway in gcp and configure it? Do you need a ready to use tool in gcp?

Comment: @jrichardsz, company requirements. Not my choice.

Comment: I understand. Did you solve your question?

Comment: @JRichardsz, not yet. Trying the Kolban solution

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Google Cloud Endpoints may be a consideration.  This allows one to expose an API gateway using OpenAPI specification.

One of the core concepts is the notion of the [x-google-backend](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-backend) element which allows one to define distinct endpoints for different exposed services.

See also:

- [Cloud Endpoints documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/)

Comment: To add to this answer, Google also offers Apigee which is similar to Amazon API Gateway. https://cloud.google.com/apigee/ Very powerful product.

Comment: @kolban, that might be a nice idea, I will take a look at that. Weird is that GCP don't have something like API Gateway natively. Thanks for the help

Comment: @john-hanley, I took a look at Apigee but my company doesn't want to use something on beta. Thanks

Comment: @BernardoMorais Apigee is not a beta product. The product has been shipping for many years (since before 2010). Google acquired the company in 2016. There are new features that are beta but the core that you need has existed for a long time - longer than Google Cloud Endpoints and much longer than Amazon API Gateway.

Comment: @JohnHanley, good to know. I'll try to negotiate that, thanks